# How can I edit point object in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

I have openlayers project. There are two object in the map. Polygon and point. I want to make edit operations in this objects. For example When I click the edit button  I drag the corner of polygon, after this I want to change new polygon which have new coordinates. I did this operation for polygon but when I select the point inside of polygon I cant select point I can only select again polygon.
[When I click the edit button and select point. Point is not select only polygon selected which belongs to polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrHHF.jpg)

this is my edit code

```
function ActiveEdit() {

    var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
        wrapX: false
    });
    var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: select.getFeatures()
    });
    map.addInteraction(select);
    map.addInteraction(modify);

}
```

Comment: Do you really need to select before modifying?  See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html  If you do select and you have overlapping features then you may need to set the `multi` option on the interaction.

Comment: @Mike I added multi option then I selected point thanks but know I cant drag selected point.